# Unable to install Fedora 23 in VM using KVM on Linux Mint 17.2

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, fedora, linuxmint

I'm unable to install `Fedora-Live-Workstation-x86_64-23-10.iso` into a QEMU virtual machine using virt-manager on Linux Mint 17.2. I've verified that the SHA256 checksum on the ISO is correct. I can install a Debian ISO that is in the same folder without any difficulty, and I have been running a Debian 7 and a Windows 7 VM for months with no problems. The error I am getting is:

```
Unable to complete install: 'internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev socket,id=charchannel0,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/fedora23.org.qemu.guest_agent.0,server,nowait: Failed to bind socket: No such file or directory
qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev socket,id=charchannel0,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/fedora23.org.qemu.guest_agent.0,server,nowait: chardev: opening backend "socket" failed
'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 89, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 1873, in do_install
    guest.start_install(meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 414, in start_install
    noboot)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 478, in _create_guest
    dom = self.conn.createLinux(start_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 3202, in createLinux
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateLinux() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev socket,id=charchannel0,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/fedora23.org.qemu.guest_agent.0,server,nowait: Failed to bind socket: No such file or directory
qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev socket,id=charchannel0,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/fedora23.org.qemu.guest_agent.0,server,nowait: chardev: opening backend "socket" failed
```

I don't know if it is significant, but on the virt-manager screen where it displays "Automatically detect operating system based on install media, the newest version of Fedora that is given as an option is Fedora 20." Can someone point me in the right direction so I can get this installed? I'll be happy to provide any additional info needed. Thanks.

Comment: I originally asked this question on the Unix & Linux community and got no solutions. I now realize that was the wrong location, but can't see any way to move the original question, so I am reposting.

Comment: I don't know much about Mint. What version of virt-manager, libvirt, qemu, and kernel is this? What steps are you taking before the error occurs? What happens immediately prior to the error?

Comment: virt-manager: 1.2.1, 
libvirt: 2.0.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1.22, 
qemu: 2.0.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1.22, 
kernel: 2.0.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1.22.

All are the newest available in the Linux Mint 17.2 repos.  

This happens immediately after hitting the "Finish" button in virt-manager.

Comment: What do you do _before_ you press the "Finish" button?

Comment: I go through all the steps of adding a VM in virt-manager, just as I have for the other 4 VMs I have successfully created. I have varied the settings used, to no avail. Is there something specific you would like to know?

Comment: I just edited my question to provide some additional info about the detected OS version, in case that helps. Also, I just realized that I made a copy/paste error with the kernel version. It is 3.13.0-44.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1393842 this bug report looks really similar to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Pat's link provided the fix. This was apparently a regression in libvirt. As suggested in the launchpad thread, running `mkdir -p /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/` (followed by `chown -R libvirt-qemu:kvm qemu/channel/`) fixed the problem. Thanks pat.